# Java Simple WGS84 Lat Lon to Pixel X, Y

Tags: java, dictionary, gis, coordinates, map-projections

I've read a multitude of information regarding map projection today. The amount of information available is overwhelming.

I am attempting to simply convert lat, long values into a screen X, Y coordinate not using any map. I do not need the values projected onto any map, just on the window.

The window itself is representing approx. a 1500x1500 meter location. Lat, Long accuracy needed is to a 1/10th of a second.

What may be some simpler ways in converting lat/long representation to the screen?

I've read several articles and post regarding translation onto images, but nothing related to the natural java coordinate system.

Thanks for any insight.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When projecting to a screen, you still are projecting to a "map", so it really depends on what your map projection is. However, if you're only working in such a small area of 1500x1500 meters, you can use a simple Cartesian projection, where each pixel is an equal amount of space (i.e. if your screen is 1500 pixels, then each pixel would represent 1 meter). However, you still need to account for where you are on the earth since the length of a degree (in both latitude and longitude) can vary greatly depending on where you are. If you are working with a fixed area, you should be able to lookup the length of 1 degree at that point.

Comment: I tried using the jhlabs earlier, but there isn't a lot of documentation out there. I am aware of the details of http://calgary.rasc.ca/latlong.htm lat distance. In my mind with such a small area of concern I'd just create a ratio of screen size to meters?

Comment: @Cody yes, exactly, a ratio of pixel size to metres. That's what Jeff has written in his answer - `each pixel is an equal amount of space`